# Can't generate true orthophoto from my software

Tags: land-survey, orthophoto, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, orthorectification

I am a GIS specialist and a surveyor. Lately I'm trying to use as a surveying tool my DJI Phantom 3 pro combining with different software for generating DEM, DSM, 3d model and orthophoto. But I can't generate true orthophoto from the software I used like Agisoft or pix4d, orthophoto after generated is deformed like in the pictures below.

My workflow was:

1. I added the photos
2. I Loaded the camera positions (with EXIF info on)
3. I aligned the photos
4. I optimized camera alignment with these settings

```
Camera accuracy: 10 
Marker accuracy: 0.005 (not utilized)
Scale bar accuracy: 0.001 (not utilized)
Projection accuracy: 0.1
Tie point accuracy: 4
```

5. I builded Dense Cloud with quality Medium and depth filtering Aggressive
6. I builded mesh with surface type Height field, source data Dense cloud and face count Medium, Interpolation enabled
7. I builded texture with mapping mode Orthophoto, blending mode Mosaic, texture size 8192
8. Then I exported as orthophoto with blending mode Mosaic, enable color correction off

How can I generate a true orthophoto from this, what I did wrong here?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is your question?  What precise steps did you perform and where did what you observed start not to match what you expected?

Comment: How can i generate a true orthophoto from this application, how should i configure those and what is the workflow?

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.  Potential answerers may or may not read a trail of comments before moving on to look at the next question they might be able to answer.

Comment: Is your question how to improve the results?

Comment: Its how can i generate a true orthophono not with deformed objects and roofs in other cases, i need them to be sharped like the original photo taken

Comment: The sad fact is that there is no automated way to create a perfect Orthophoto.

Comment: So, you have to fix it manually through seamline editing?

Comment: It may be true that no perfect orthophoto can be automatically generated, but this is very far from perfect. I've also used Agisoft with drone images and the result was pretty much okay. Have you looked at the positioning errors for cameras after aligning? Maybe there' s something wrong with that. Also, in the File menu you have an option to generate a pdf report with error estimates and other data, if you could share it with us maybe it'll give us a clue about the problem.

Answer (score 2):

While I understand it is about pricing and the cost but have you looked at it here http://www.ips-match.com/
I myself have not tried this since I only use ERDAS or ENVI.

You can try and google "Orthophotos software" and it came up a few software that might be free or commerical.

One thing I attend ERSI's Dronemap and really nice program they had and you would need the pictures and it will take care of your orthophotos...

http://www.esri.com/products/drone2map

Check this out https://dronemapper.com/

and what software are you using when you are trying to perform surveying tool ?

Comment: As i understood from this process, because now i have more experience :) is that it needs to do some manually work with mosaic editor and to choose the right planar images from certain area. As i see image overlapping is not enough and it doesn't have enough information to generate a correct orthophoto.

Comment: and sometimes there are enough photos to create a point cloud but not enough for an orthophoto, the point clouds are usually pretty good, but then the software kind of stretches your raw images over the point using little bits from each. Also trees are very difficult and sometimes need a higher flying height to get optimal results due to parallax errors.